# How to display character string literals with hex properly with std::cout in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, escaping, cout

**How to display character string literals with hex properly with std::cout in C++?**

I want to use octal and hex to print character string literals with std::cout in C++.

I want to print "bee".

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "b\145e" << std::endl;//1
    std::cout << "b\x65e" << std::endl;//2
    return 0;
}
```

//1 works fine, but //2 doesn't with hex escape sequence out of range.

Now  I want to print "be3".

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "b\1453" << std::endl;//1
    std::cout << "b\x653" << std::endl;//2
    return 0;
}
```

Also, //1 works fine, but //2 doesn't with hex escape sequence out of range.

Now can I come to the conclusion that **hex is not a good way to display character string characters**?

I get the feeling I am wrong but don't know why.

Can someone explain whether hex can be used and how?

Comment: When I use escaping in code (which converts arbitrary strings into C-like escaped), I prefer formatting of non-printable characters with octal numbers and output always 3 digits. That prevents mis-interpretings of following characters because octal encoding is limited to 3 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually an example of this exact same situation on cppreference's [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) on string literals.

> If a valid hex digit follows a hex escape in a string literal, it would fail to compile as an invalid escape sequence. String concatenation can be used as a workaround:

They provide the example below:

```
// const char* p = "\xfff"; // error: hex escape sequence out of range
const char* p = "\xff""f";  // OK   : the literal is const char[3] holding {'\xff','f','\0'}
```

Applying what they explain to your problem, we can print the string literal `be3` in two ways:

```
std::cout << "b\x65" "3" << std::endl;
std::cout << "b\x65" << "3" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The hex escape sequences becomes `\x65e` and `\x653` so you need to help the compiler to stop after `65`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "b\x65""e" << std::endl;//2
    std::cout << "b\x65""3" << std::endl;//2
}
```